# PHP Syntax getting PHP terms

Tags: php, plugins

I'm trying to figure out the php syntax here, so I can show only related products that are of the current taxonomy term. I would like the $args filter 'product_brand' to dynamically grab the current products term.

So I need a method of getting the slug for the current product term. I've tried this but it's not working, and is returning more than one term.

`$mjrelatedproducts = get_brands( $post->ID )->slug;`

```
$args = apply_filters('woocommerce_related_products_args', array(
    'post_type'             => 'product',
    'ignore_sticky_posts'   => 1,
    'product_brand'         => $mjrelatedproducts,
    'no_found_rows'         => 1,
    'posts_per_page'        => $posts_per_page,
    'orderby'               => $orderby,
    'post__in'              => $related,
    'post__not_in'          => array($product->id)
) );
```

Comment: But what if the current product/post has multiple brands?

Comment: The Products are set to only ever have one brand

Comment: does the API written for everybody not just you know that though? If I make sure my blog posts are only ever in 1 tag at a time, that doesn't magically change all the APIs, I still get arrays back even if they only have 1 thing in them

Comment: hmm, I'm not sure. I do seem to be getting multiple results, which I didn't think would happen. I assumed I would get no results at all if its was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

What about just using [`get_the_terms()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms)?

```
<?php get_the_terms( $id, $taxonomy ); ?>
```

Comment: How would i apply that to the args array? For example, the term slug on the page I'm testing it on is 'aat' this is the return i would need.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use get_the_ID() for things like that, which will return the ID of the current page/post.

```
$mjrelatedproducts = get_brands( get_the_ID() )->slug;
```

That should return the slug of the current page/post.